# Compile MQ5 file with VS Code extension on linux

Tags: mql5

I'd like to compile a mq5 file by using Visual Studio Code on linux operating system.

Would be great to use an extension like "MQL tools" but, this extension seems to be working on Windows only.

My Metatrader runs by using Wine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can compile MQL5 manually from the terminal in Linux using Wine like this:

```bash
wine /path/to/editor.exe /compile:path/to/file.mq5 /log:$/path/to/log.log
```

Mine looks like this for example:

```bash
wine /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MetaEditor64.exe /compile:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/Experts/test.mq5 /log:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log
```

---

**⚠️ Important note ⚠️** :  *MQL will not compile if you have any spaces anywhere in the file path.*

Because the `Program Files` directory in Wine and my MetaTrader directory, `PU Prime MT5 Terminal`, both have spaces I ran this command to create a symlink and have a directory path without spaces:

```bash
ln -s "${HOME}/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PU Prime MT5 Terminal" "${HOME}/.wine/PUPrime"
```

`/home/juan/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/PU Prime MT5 Terminal`

becomes

`/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime`

---

#### If you actually want to see what happened when you compiled you can do something like this:

```bash
echo -n '' > /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log

wine /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MetaEditor64.exe /compile:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/Experts/test.mq5 /log:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log

cat /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log
```

**The first line just clears the compiler log and the last line reads the log into terminal*

#### If you want to be able to do it directly from VSCode you could save above into a bash script and then use a VSCode Task to call it like this:

tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "MQL COMPILE",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/compile_script.sh",
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

compile_script.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if a filename is provided & extract it
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Error: Missing filename argument."
    exit 1
fi
filename="$1"

# First Task: Clear log
echo "Running MQL: clear log"
echo -n '' > /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log

# Second Task: Compile file
echo "Running MQL: compilel"
wine /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MetaEditor64.exe /compile:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/${filename} /log:/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log

# Third task: Real log
echo "Running MQL: read log"
cat /home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/loggity.log
```

---

## My Setup

##### Here is the bash script I use instead of the one above:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
clear

# Set filename and syntax flag
arg1_filename="$1"
arg2_syntax_flag="${2:-}"

# Paths
LogFullPath="/home/juan/.wine/MQL5/loggity.log"
EditorFullPath="/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MetaEditor64.exe"
CompileFullPath="/home/juan/.wine/PUPrime/MQL5/${arg1_filename}"

# Clear log
> "$LogFullPath"

# Compile or check syntax
wine "$EditorFullPath" "/compile:$CompileFullPath" "/log:$LogFullPath" "$arg2_syntax_flag" > /dev/null 2>&1 

# Read log
printf " ⌛  %s: %s\n" "$([ -n "$arg2_syntax_flag" ] && echo "Checking Syntax" || echo "Compiling")" "$arg1_filename"
Log=$(iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 "$LogFullPath" | tac)                          # Convert to UTF-8, reverse order

while IFS= read -r line; do  
                                                                                # Read log line by line
    if [[ "$line" =~ 0\ errors,\ 0\ warning ]]; then                        
        printf "\e[38:5:114m ✅  0 Errors, 0 Warnings!\e[0m\n"                  # Green Line: no errors, no warnings
        exit 0                                                              
    elif [[ "$line" =~ :\ error|:\ warning ]]; then                         
        num=$(echo "$line" | sed -n 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p')                 # Extract error/warning line number
        msg=$(echo "$line" | sed -n 's/.*[0-9]\+:\ \(.*\)$/\1/p')               # Extract error/warning message
        loc=$(echo "$line" | sed -n 's/.*[\\\/]\(.*\)([0-9]*,[0-9]*).*$/\1/p')  # Extract error/warning location 

        if [[ "$line" == *": error"* ]]; then 
            printf "\e[0;38;5;196m❌ %s\t%s  %s\e[0m\n" "$num" "$loc" "$msg"    # Red Line: error
        else                
            printf "\e[0;38;5;220m️  %s\t%s  %s\e[0m\n" "$num" "$loc" "$msg"   #Yellow Line: warning         
        fi
    fi
done <<< "$Log"

exit 0
```

**Note that this hides a lot of information, just tells you if your file compiles correctly and if not shows only the errors and warnings. Formatted for easier readability and also accepts the syntax check flag*

##### Syntax check only

The MetaTrader compiler lets you also just check the syntax of your file instead of a doing a full compile by adding a `/s` flag to the command. This is nice because it's much faster than a full compile, especially if  you project has a lot of includes in it. The compile code can take `/s` flag as argument as well to run the syntax check.

##### tasks.json

Here we have a separate task just for the syntax check:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "MQL COMPILE",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_script.sh",
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "clear": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "MQL SYNTAX CHECK",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_script.sh",
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}",
                "/s"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "panel": "dedicated",
                "clear": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Keybinding

The compile task is set as the default build task so it has an automatic keybinding. But the syntax check task needs its own keybinding in keybinding.json:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+enter ctrl+shift+enter",     // Specify your desired key combination
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
        "args": "MQL SYNTAX CHECK",                     // Replace with the label of your task
        "when": "resourceExtname == '.mq4' || resourceExtname == '.mq5' || resourceExtname == '.mqh'"
    }
```